# JMeter Extract Redirected Request Body URL

Tags: url, redirect, jmeter, extractor

GET https://www.example/a/resource1?id=24   - I have this URL

This gets redirected to https://www.example/a/resource1-New-York   - I need this URL  -- This is how it looks like in the View Tree

[image: View Tree Sampler View In Request Body]

I have tried extracting using the Extractor but doesn't work
This is how looks like in the Extractor

[image: Regular Expression Extractor]

I get Not Found in the variable

Comment: @Zohair this is JMeter 5 screenshots

Comment: Did my answer using `(.*)` helped?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the GET prefix, get all URL with

```
(.*)
```

Or without http://

```
http://(.*)
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem use Regular Expression Extractor and remove GET Protocol. Example is given below:

[image]

[image]